# Ruby web server that support reverse proxy?

Tags: ruby, passenger, puma

I wonder if there is any high performance ruby webserver that suport reverse proxy like `rack-reverse-proxy` does, or `ProxyPass` / `ProxyPassReverse` in apache.

Please note I DONT want to use apache / nginx as a proxy, but a ruby webserver like puma or passenger.

Why? because I've a blog using wordpress running on /blog

Comment: `high performance ruby` is a bit of an oxymoron. whats wrong with `rack-reverse-proxy`

Comment: You probably want something sitting in front of both WordPress and Ruby that is properly routing requests to the appropriate backend systems based on the URL. For example, an NGINX instance could be routing /blog to PHP-FPM and everything else to Puma.

Comment: Yes, my problem is that rails app is on heroku and WP is on another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NginX + Unicorn is a good way to do this.

See: 
http://sirupsen.com/setting-up-unicorn-with-nginx/

http://railscasts.com/episodes/293-nginx-unicorn

Comment: he specifically said he doesn't want nginx.

Comment: I missed that in his question

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to proxy WP `/blog` through Ruby? What's wrong with NginX.
You can simply proxy `/blog` (A simple `location /blog` in NginX block would do the trick) to PHP-FPM and others to Puma (Ruby) from NginX.

This would be direct approach. Or is there any specific reason for you to proxy PHP via Ruby?

Comment: I've the rails app running in heroku, and the WP on other hosting provider, what would be the best solution?

Comment: Oh, I thought, both on same hosting.
For different hosting, I would prefer to keep it in separate subdomain, something like: `blog.example.com`